# Export Sub-Function in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to export `update()` *sub-function* from [following module](https://github.com/spiermar/d3-flame-graph/blob/master/dist/d3.flameGraph.js) which looks like:

```
function flameGraph() {   // parent function
    .....

    function update() {   // sub-function
       .....
    }

}
```

I've tried the following without much success:

[L396](https://github.com/spiermar/d3-flame-graph/blob/master/dist/d3.flameGraph.js#L396)

```
module.exports = update // <= rewrites module.exports = flameGraph (?)
```

[L603](https://github.com/spiermar/d3-flame-graph/blob/master/dist/d3.flameGraph.js#603)

```
module.exports = { flameGraph, update } // <= sub-function update is not defined, because called out of scope
```

I'm really sorry for cumbersome description of the question. The module is heavy enough to paste its content on StackOverflow.

Comment: I downvote because you have really the very bad way to represent your question. You must update your question with proper description

Comment: Thanks for honesty @Dipakchavda. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `update` as method of `chart` (which is the object that the main function `flameGraph` returns)

```
// add this line on L597
chart.update = update;
```

then call `flameGraphInstance.update()`

Example:

```
let flameGraphInstance = flameGraph();
// ... do stuff ... 
flameGraphInstance.update();
```

Comment: Thanks. After adding `chart.update = update` to `L597` as you suggested and exported `flameGraphInstance` in another file still getting not defined error
       `flameGraphInstance = require('./d3.flameGraph.custom');
        console.log(flameGraphInstance);  // OK
        console.log('UPDATE', flameGraphInstance.update()); // UPDATE IS NOT DEFINED`

Comment: You are missing the function call ` () `

Comment: require('./d3.flameGraph.custom')()

Comment: Thanks @luca-rainone That was it! Marking as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just have flameGraph return the update function!

```
module.exports = function() {
 ...
return {update}
}


let flameGraphInstance = require('./FlameGraph')()
// ... do stuff ... 
flameGraphInstance.update();
```

Comment: Thanks @robert-moskal. Appreciate your help.